# Visual Studio C++ compiler fails because include file name is too long

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, include-path

My application contains multiple sub folders, that can go quite deep, e.g.

```
library\management\security\descriptor\configurations
```

*(this is just a fictive example)*

If another part of my application needs an include file of this folder it writes this:

```
#include "library\management\security\descriptor\configurations\config.h"
```

The problem is that if the file that contains this include is also in a quite deep path, like this:

```
people\groups\interestgroups\manager.cpp
```

And we have checked out our project in the folder:

```
E:\jenkins\workspace\application\release\flavour
```

Then the Visual Studio compiler (we compile using the `/I.` (slash-I-dot) option) first looks for the file in this location:

```
E:\jenkins\workspace\application\release\flavour\people\groups\interestgroups\library\management\security\descriptor\configurations\config.h"
```

And then only in

```
E:\jenkins\workspace\application\release\flavour\library\management\security\descriptor\configurations\config.h"
```

(this behavior is described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/36k2cdd4(v=vs.100).aspx).
So it insists in looking first in the place where the compiled file is, and then only looking at the `/I` option.

The problem is that the place where the compiler looks first results in a filename that is too long (>256 characters) and the compiler just gives up.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to not stop when an include path is too long?  Preferably without using the bracket include format (`#include <>`).

Comment: One workaround is that you can just add the path to the include path list. Might not help always though

Comment: @gldraphael If I understand him correctly, the path is in the include path list.  The problem is that the first place searched is the directory where the file with the include is.  And apparently, VS is trying to use an absolute path name for this.

Comment: The issue appears to be a Visual Studio restriction which they are not planning to address. I have a possible 'horrible' solution, but it may work. What if you were to map the folder "E:\jenkins\workspace\application\release\flavour" to a driver letter such as Z. Then you set the include path to "Z:\".

Answer (score 0):

You can just make file in interestgroups folder that only include config.h file and you just include interestgroups file and use that file